# Pig 0.12.0 - extracting last two characters from a string

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera, bigdata

I am using `CDH 5.5`, `Pig 0.12.0`. I have a `chararray` like this: `25 - 45` and I want to extract 25 and 45 out of this String.

So, I did this:

```
minValue = (int)SUBSTRING(value,0,2);
maxValue = ((int)SUBSTRING(value,6,2);
```

I am able to extract `minValue` but unable to extract the `maxValue` i.e. last two characters of the given String.

Even I tried but this one is also not working.:

```
maxValue = ((int)SUBSTRING(value,-2,2);
```

Please let me know how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If delimeter is colon ( - ) always, then we can split and flatten the chararray to extract min and max value.

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (min_max:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(min_max,' - ',0)) AS (min_val:chararray, max_val:chararray);
DUMP B;
```

**Input :**

```
25 - 45
35 - 65
45 - 85
```

**Output :**

```
(25,45)
(35,65)
(45,85)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the index of the specific character in the SUBSTRING function.

Here is what you need.

```
maxValue = (int)SUBSTRING(value,5,7);
```

Comment: Is not there a way to read from the end of the string by giving a negative value?

Comment: When I give negative index, UDF is returning StringIndexOutOfBoundsException : String index out of range. So I guess it doesn't support negative values.